# data.setValue google chart set dynamically

Tags: google-visualization

I've got all of the values for my data.setValue stored in an array. All the examples I find are as follow:

```
data.setValue(0,0,"Germany");
data.setValue(0,1,200);
```

I want to be able to loop through my array of values and pass them to data.setValue. I currently have something like this:

```
var finalCountries = []; <br>
finalCountries=[[Germany,200],[US,300],[Australia,400]];

for (var p=0; p < finalCountries.length; p++){

  data.setValue(p,p,finalCountries[p][0]);
  data.setValue(p,p+1,finalCountries[p][1]);

}
```

This is not working since its passing only the last value of the loop. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the fix data.SetValue needs to always have (0,0) and then (0,1) as its initial values. I was using p that increases within the loop hence the miss match